# Unstoppable service

Tags: android, foreground-service

I try ti write a app that will monitor charge level of the phone for all the time, so I try to build unstoppable service. But for now, when I close app it didn't send me any notifications.

Here is my code:

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

<service
        android:name=".NotificationService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETE"
        android:process=":BatMonitoring">
    </service>

    <receiver
        android:name=".BootReceiver"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"
        android:enabled="true">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.REBOOT"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>

    </receiver>
```

**MainActivity.java**(main part of code)

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    batteryLevel = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.battery_level);
    voltageLevel = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.voltage_level);
    temperatureLevel = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.temperature_level);

    registerReceiver(this.mBatInfoReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));

    Intent intentService = new Intent(this,NotificationService.class);
    startService(intentService);
}
```

**BootReceiver.java**

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, NotificationService.class);
        context.startService(serviceIntent);
}
```

}

**NotificationService.java**

```
public class NotificationService extends Service implements Constants {

private String title;
private String msg;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    this.registerReceiver(this.mBatteryInfoReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));

}


public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    sendNotif(START_MSG1,START_MSG2);
    return START_STICKY;

}

    BroadcastReceiver mBatteryInfoReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            int level = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
            int chargeState = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, -1);
            boolean isDischarging = chargeState == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_DISCHARGING;

            if (isDischarging && title!=null && msg!=null) {


                    switch(level){

                        //some other not important code

                    }
                sendNotif(title, msg);

            }

        }

    };

private void sendNotif(String title, String msg) {
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(NotificationService.this)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(msg)
            .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_notify_chat);

    Notification notification = builder.build();
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

    startForeground(DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
}




@Override
    public void onDestroy () {
        super.onDestroy();

        this.unregisterReceiver(this.mBatteryInfoReceiver);

        startService(new Intent(this,NotificationService.class));

       //Disabling service
       //stopSelf();
    }

@Override
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
    super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
    startService(new Intent(this,NotificationService.class));
}


public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
```

}

Will appreciate any help, because I can't cope with this problem for more then week.

Comment: an "unstoppable service" does not exist and even if it would be possible, you will upset the users. The only way to get near such one is to deal with the doze mode, I guess this is what your service stops.https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html

Comment: @Opiatefuchs, but there are a lot of app's like facebook,viber, or even alarm clock that work in foreground for all time

Comment: No they don´t, they just do a trick. This is a huge topic, especially since doze mode in MM. It starts with what you return in onStartCommand of the service, see the docs https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY

Comment: I don´t know what exactly facebook or what´s app does, but I guess, they keep themselve alive by for example fire alarmManager setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(). Also there are other options inside the article I showed you in my first comment.

Comment: There are so many options to try to keep your service alive, but at the end, if the user decides to kill it, it should not be avoided. Also, if the system is overloaded, it kills the service too, no matter what you are doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are looking for a **background service** as opposed to an app.  The official documentation can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html).

Background services do not have a user interface.

[Here is a good tutorial](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2014/01/android-service-tutorial.html).